# Multiple operations on Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate, median

I am trying to group by one/two columns, Sum the value of forth column and find mean in fifth column. Every operation to be written in separate output. Feels a bit tricky to make even a start.

Input: No header, has more than 100k rows

```
StartTime, EndTime,Day,SumCount,UniqueCount
00:00:00,01:00:00,Mon,13534,594
01:00:00,02:00:00,Mon,16674,626
02:00:00,03:00:00,Mon,23736,671
03:00:00,04:00:00,Mon,16977,671
00:00:00,01:00:00,Tue,17262,747
01:00:00,02:00:00,Tue,19072,777
02:00:00,03:00:00,Tue,18275,785
03:00:00,04:00:00,Tue,13589,757
04:00:00,05:00:00,Tue,16053,735
05:00:00,06:00:00,Tue,11440,636
```

I am trying to find is

1. Groupby `StartTime`  & `EndTime` find Sum of `SumCount` and Median of `UniqueCount`
2. Groupby `Day`find Sum of `SumCount` and Median of `UniqueCount`

I am lost how to put the two types of groupby in one program and get two different output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df.groupby(['StartTime', 'EndTime']).agg({'SumCount': ['sum'],
                             'UniqueCount': {'median': lambda x: np.median(x).round(0)}})
```

[image]

Or:

```
df.groupby(['Day']).agg({'SumCount': ['sum'],
                         'UniqueCount': {'median': lambda x: np.median(x).round(0)}})
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  But I cannot have float value for median. How do I round off that?

Comment: @SitzBlogz Updated post

Comment: Thank you so much.  If I get any error will write back.  Thanks again 